# How to get all columns from one table and one column from another table in SQLITE

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have 2 tables with the same column names but with different data. Consider the following:

Table1 Structure:

```
id, sid, text
1,  1,   'Hello World'
2,  1,   'Hello World again'
3,  2,   'Hw...'
4,  2,   'Hw2...'
```

And Table2:

```
id, sid, text
1,  1,   'Hello World 2'
2,  1,   'Hello World again 2'
3,  2,   'Hw2...'
4,  2,   'Hw22...'
```

I want to query "Table1" based on "sid". For example, if sid is 1 then I should get 2 rows as a result with all columns from "Table1" but just column "text" from "Table2". Like this:

```
id, sid, text,                  text
1,  1,   'Hello World',        'Hello World2'
2,  1,   'Hello World again',  'Hello World again 2'
```

I am trying to INNER JOIN But I get repition:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.text FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.sid = Table2.sid WHERE Table1.sid = 1;
```

But I am getting duplicate rows! How can I solve this? I know there are many similar questions but I could not find one with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use sid and id to identify the right row

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, t2.text
FROM
    Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
    Table2 t2 ON t1.sid = t2.sid AND t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    Tt1.sid = 1;
```